# How to get records with distinct column value from result set in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, aggregate-functions, min

could you please help me on the below query?

Using the query

```
SELECT LineGernal.Id, LineGernal.Description, LineGernal.SSMS, BaseAddOns.Id
from LineGernal Inner Join
     BaseAddOns
     on LineGernal.Id=BaseAddOns.ParentLineGernalID
```

Output-

[image: Output]

Result Needed-

[image: Result Needed]

Thanks
Rajendra

Comment: You probably need `GROUP BY`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes Gordon i tried group by

Comment: Hint, use `min` with `baseaddonsid` and remove that field from the `group by`....

Comment: Hi Gordon i using like this  -  SELECT LineGernal.Id,LineGernal.Description,LineGernal.SSMS,BaseAddOns.Id from LineGernal
Inner Join BaseAddOns on LineGernal.Id=BaseAddOns.ParentLineGernalID group by LineGernal.Id,LineGernal.Description,LineGernal.SSMS,BaseAddOns.Id

Comment: Hi  sgeddes, thanks a lot ..it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and min as follows:

```
SELECT LineGernal.Id, LineGernal.Description, LineGernal.SSMS, min(BaseAddOns.Id) as id
from LineGernal Inner Join
     BaseAddOns
     on LineGernal.Id=BaseAddOns.ParentLineGernalID 
GROUO BY LineGernal.Id, LineGernal.Description, LineGernal.SSMS
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend pre-aggregation in a subquery:

```
select li.id as lineGeneralId, lg.description, lg.ssms, bao.id as BaseAddOnsId
from LineGernal lg 
inner join (
    select ParentLineGernalID, min(id) as id
    from BaseAddOns 
    group by ParentLineGernalID, 
) bao on lg.id = bao.ParentLineGernalID
```